# Seperate Vue.js project with laravel sanctum does not set cookie

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, cookies, laravel-sanctum

I’m trying to create a dashboard (Vue.js) that I can use for my website (Laravel). They are running locally on https://example.test and http://admin.example.test:8080 respectively.

When I try to login from my Vue dashboard I first make a request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` and all goes well.
After that I try to go to `/login`, but I get a CSRF-TOKEN mismatch. I’ve googled around for a solution, but nothing worked so far.

The problem is that it does not set the cookie from the `set-cookie` header returned by Laravel.

What have I tried:

**Vue.js side:**

Setting axios headers

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'admin.example.test'
axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
};
```

**Laravel side:**

Added to .env file

```
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=false
SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.test
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=admin.example.test:8080
```

config/cors.php looks like:

```
'paths' => [
        'api/*',
        'login',
        'logout',
        'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
    ],

    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: Just to confirm, you have included `EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful` middleware in the Kernal `api` configuration and are you sending the `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header?

Comment: @Peppermintology First one yes, the second one No. This is because it's failing to set the sanctum cookie.

Comment: So your request to `/sanctum/csrf-cookie` isn't going well then?

Comment: @Peppermintology Well it returns a 204 response, so that's good. But the set-cookie header is not setting the cookie.